# Read a file in Asynchronous mode in C#, VS 2008

Tags: c#, file-io

can you provide a sample code or links on 
how to read a file line by line in **Asynchronous mode**??

I have to read a file one line at a time (or at least 30 bytes of data) and display it in a text box, say textBox1. To do this I have to use asynchronous read mode. How can i acheive this??

i am using C# windows application
IDE - visual studio 2008

Comment: Read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), please

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) What didn't work? What difficulties did you encounter? What is your question?

Comment: ive been searching a lot.. am a beginner in File operations. Got some idea about synchronous file reading. But i cant get any help regarding this asynchronous read.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? The [`FileStream.BeginRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxt5ahzw.aspx) is probably the method I would start with.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxt5ahzw.aspx) method. For example you could define a state object that will contain information about the stream and contents being read:

```
public class State
{
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }
    public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
}
```

and then begin reading the file in chunks of 30 bytes asynchronously:

```
var stream = File.OpenRead("SomeFile.txt");
var state = new State
{
    Stream = stream,
    Buffer = new byte[30]
};
stream.BeginRead(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, EndRead, state);
```

The `EndRead` method could be defined like this:

```
private void EndRead(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var state = ar.AsyncState as State;
    var bytesRead = state.Stream.EndRead(ar);
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        string value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        // TODO: do something with the value being read
        // Warning: if this is a desktop application such as WinForms
        // and you need to update some control on the GUI make sure that 
        // you marshal the call on the main UI thread, because this EndRead
        // method will be invoked on a thread drawn from the thread pool.
        // In WinForms you need to use Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke
        // method to marshal the call on the UI thread.

        state.Stream.BeginRead(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, EndRead, state);
    }
    else
    {
        // finished reading => dispose the FileStream
        state.Stream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: File.OpenRead method is equivalent to the FileStream(String, FileMode, FileAccess, FileShare) constructor overload with a FileMode value of Open, a FileAccess value of Read and a FileShare value of Read.
Will this Begin an asynchronous read operation?

Comment: No, this will not begin an asynchronous read operation. It only opens a file handle. It's the `stream.BeginRead` method that begins the asynchronous read operation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to read a file from another thread.
See if [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/csharplanguage/thread/70784fe4-2b89-4d58-ae05-38bff94c3006) helps you, since it's hard to understand what exactly you're trying to do..

Also, as @Darin mentioned in a comment you should read about the [FileStream.BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxt5ahzw.aspx) method.
Note that if you're using .Net 4.5 you can the [ReadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.readasync.aspx) method.